# How To Safely Downgrade PHP (7.1 to 7.0) on CentOS

Tags: centos, php, yum

I have a mission-critical production CentOS server running PHP7.1 from the remi repo. I need to downgrade PHP to 7.0. How can I do safely do this (What commands) with no downtime? Here's some output to provide some context.

```
# yum info php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.linux.duke.edu
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.linux.duke.edu
 * remi-php71: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * updates: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
Installed Packages
Name        : php
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 7.1.12
Release     : 4.el7.remi
Size        : 9.4 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : remi-php71
Summary     : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
```

How I originally upgraded to PHP7.1 was by enabling the remi php7.1 repo for PHP so now printing info for just `php` package shows the php7.1 package info as seen above. What I need is for `yum info php` to return the php 7.0 package that can be found in remi's `php70` package:

```
# yum info php70
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.linux.duke.edu
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.linux.duke.edu
 * remi-php71: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * updates: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
Available Packages
Name        : php70
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.0
Release     : 5.el7.remi
Size        : 2.9 k
Repo        : remi-safe
Summary     : Package that installs PHP 7.0
License     : GPLv2+
Description : This is the main package for php70 Software Collection,
            : that install PHP 7.0 language.
```

What commands would accomplish that and replace php7.1 with php7.0?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with `yum downgrade`. The command in your case should be something like

```
yum downgrade php
```

which will give you the actions that yum will do and the option to proceed. You may have to do

```
yum --disablerepo remi-php71 downgrade php
```

if the first command doesn't show a downgrade path.

As always, test this before doing it on a production machine.

Comment: You have to disable remi-php71 and enable the remi-php70 one. Then the yum downgrade command have to list all installed extensions (rpm -qa php\*) including pecl packages.

Comment: @RemiCollet I don't suppose you'd consider writing that up as a full answer?  It'd be nice to have one from the horse's mouth, as it were.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check yum history with `yum history` command. If you find step, where you install PHP7.1 instead of PHP7.0, you could revert it by `yum history undo <Step ID>`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to downgrade most PHP-versions installed using the remi-repo.

You probably already have remi-php71.repo and remi-php70.repo in etc/yum.repos.d/ If you don't have a repo file for the version you want to downgrade to, make sure to install that first.

Disable the current version by editing the file for that version (remi-php71.repo) and changing `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`

Enable the version you want to downgrade to by editing the file for that version (remi-php70.repo) and changing the first `enabled=0` to `enabled=1` (attention: only the first one, don't accidentally enable to one under debuginfo or test)

Then:

```
sudo yum downgrade php
```

You'll probably receive a number of messages like this one

```
Error: Package: php-7.x.remi.x86_64 (remi-php7x)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.x.el7.remi
```

Based on that error, you should add php-common to your command:

```
sudo yum downgrade php php-common
```

extra errors will probably be returned, which will include other packages that need to be included in your yum downgrade command. Keep adding them to the list. After a couple of attempts, yum should be happy to actually carry out the downgrade.

Check if it was successful:

```
php -version
```

Don't forget to restart php-fpm if you use this.

Comment: simple way after switching the repository is to use "yum distro-sync"